# Interactively send email with empty message body in Mutt

Tags: email, vim, mutt

I use Mutt as my email client with Vim configured as my editor.  Every now and again, I want to send an email (usually to myself) that has an empty message body, e.g., the message has a *Subject* line and an attachment.

When composing such an email, I enter a subject line and recipient address and then Vim opens to allow me to edit the message body. I have to enter some whitespace before saving and closing the temporary file. If I simply quit Vim without entering any text (using the `:q` or `:x` commands), I get the following error message and am returned to the mailbox folder index.

> Aborted unmodified message.

I’m aware that I can use the command line to send such a message:

```
 echo | mutt -s "Subject Line" -a attachment.zip anthony@example.com
```

However, I’d like to be able to do this while using Mutt interactively. Is there a configuration variable that can be set to allow empty message bodies?

I looked through the documentation on the Mutt website and used both DuckDuckGo and Google to search for the phrase “Aborted unmodified message” but all the results seem to be related to users who did not have their `editor` variable set correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this line to your `.muttrc` file

```
set abort_unmodified = no
```

Documented in `man muttrc` and the [online manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#abort-unmodified):

> If set to *yes*, composition will automatically abort after editing the
>   message body if no changes are made to the file (this check only happens
>   after the *first* edit of the file). When set to *no*, composition will
>   never be aborted.

Comment: Excellent. I've accepted your answer and edited it to add a reference to and quote from the relevant section in the manual. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Mutt notes the modification time of the temporary message body file before starting Vim, then checks it again after Vim exits. If the modification time is unchanged, Mutt doesn't send the email message and issues `Aborted unmodified message`.

An easy way to avoid that is to simply write the empty buffer with `:w` before closing Vim.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I've been using `:wq` for the past few years but I’ve just accepted [ovmjm’s recently posted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1527526/247588) as a better solution for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$editor` to your advantage here.

First, write a small script that looks for something in particular that indicates that this should be an empty-body e-mail. For example, you could put some special character as the first character in the Subject field value.

If the script doesn't detect that indicator, then it should just launch your regular editor normally.

If it *does* detect that indicator, however, it should `touch` the message file (which is given as the first parameter in the `$editor` invocation) and return. You may also want to make it such that it removes that indicator, so that if you hit `e` for edit you get your regular editor.

That can be put together with a little bit of `formail` and your text processor (awk, sed, ...) of choice.

Set Mutt's `$editor` to call that script instead of `vim`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Michael. That's quite a clever solution. I had never considered setting the `$editor` variable to a wrapper script.  For the moment, I'll stick with garyjohn's simpler approach.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I have a script like that to do some pre-processing of the e-mail body before passing it to the visual editor, though not for the exact purpose you are looking for. Works like a charm.

Comment: Another idea would be to use a macro when sending those empty-body emails to set and restore the value of `editor`. _I have not tested this_--it's mostly food for thought--but I use something similar for another purpose. `macro index ,m ': set editor=touch<Return><edit>: set editor=vim<Return>'`. *Update:* That's not going to do what you want. I'll experiment a little.

Comment: Never mind. `<edit>` doesn't require any further input from the keyboard but `<mail>` does. I can't figure out how to restore the value of `editor` after executing `<mail>` in a single macro.

Comment: @garyjohn Guessing wildly, but did you try `source`ing a configuration file that pushes the relevant commands onto the queue? Hackish as h, but every time I've thought Mutt couldn't be trained to perform some particular trick, there turned out to be a way...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: No, I hadn't tried that, but I just did and nothing I tried worked. If I pushed all the commands, then they all went into the keyboard buffer and were read into the `<mail>` command's prompts for `To: `, etc. If I put the set commands without `push` or `exec` into the script (`set editor=touch`, `exec mail, `set editor=vim`), then the last `set` command was executed before the `mail` command so that the editor was still vim.